When transferring money on the TON chain, such as USDT, the code always recognizes it as sending TON coins. Why?
Regarding the processing of Jetton transfers on TON, I need to implement the transfer completely on the backend. That is, provide my own wallet mnemonic to transfer USDT to multiple addresses through my own account.
const { Address, beginCell, toNano, TonClient, WalletContractV4, internal } = require("ton");
const { mnemonicToWalletKey } = require("@ton/crypto");

async function checkJettonWalletAddress(client, jettonMasterAddress, walletAddress) {
    const { stack } = await client.callGetMethod(Address.parse(jettonMasterAddress), 'get_wallet_address', [
        { type: 'slice', cell: beginCell().storeAddress(walletAddress).endCell() }
    ]);
    const jettonWalletAddress = stack.readAddress();
    return jettonWalletAddress.toString();
}

async function checkJettonBalance(client, jettonWalletAddress) {
    const { stack } = await client.callGetMethod(Address.parse(jettonWalletAddress.toString()), 'get_wallet_data');
    const balance = stack.readBigNumber();
    return balance.toString();
}

async function transferJettonTokens(fromMnemonic, toAddress, jettonMasterAddress, transferAmount) {
    const client = new TonClient({
        endpoint: 'https://toncenter.com/api/v2/jsonRPC',
        apiKey: 'xxx'
    });

    try {
        const key = await mnemonicToWalletKey(fromMnemonic.split(" "));
        const wallet = WalletContractV4.create({ publicKey: key.publicKey, workchain: 0, subwalletId: 1 });
        const walletContract = client.open(wallet);

        const jettonWalletAddress = await checkJettonWalletAddress(client, jettonMasterAddress, wallet.address);
        const jettonBalanceBefore = await checkJettonBalance(client, jettonWalletAddress);

        const forwardAmount = toNano('0.000000001'); // 1 nanotons for forward fee
        const transferFee = toNano('0.05'); // 0.05 TON for transfer fee

        const balance = await walletContract.getBalance();
        const queryId = BigInt(Date.now()); // 
        console.log('transferAmount:', transferAmount);
        const transferBody = beginCell()
            .storeUint(0xf8a7ea5, 32) // transfer op
            .storeUint(queryId, 64) // 
            .storeCoins(toNano("1"))
            .storeAddress(Address.parse(toAddress)) 
            .storeAddress(Address.parse(toAddress))
            .storeUint(0, 1) // no custom payload
            .storeCoins(toNano("2"))
            .storeUint(0,1) // no forward payload
            .endCell();

        console.log('transferFee:', transferFee);


        const externalMessage = walletContract.sendTransfer({
            seqno: await walletContract.getSeqno(),
            secretKey: key.secretKey,
            messages: [
                internal({
                    to: jettonWalletAddress,
                     value: toNano("0.2").toString(),
                    body: transferBody.toBoc().toString('base64'), 
                    bounce: false 
                })
             
            ]
        });

        let currentSeqno = await walletContract.getSeqno();
        let attempts = 0;
        const maxAttempts = 10;
        while (currentSeqno == await walletContract.getSeqno() && attempts < maxAttempts) {
            console.log('wating:', attempts + 1);
            await sleep(1500);
            currentSeqno = await walletContract.getSeqno();
            attempts++;
        }

        if (currentSeqno > await walletContract.getSeqno()) {
            const jettonBalanceAfter = await checkJettonBalance(client, jettonWalletAddress);
            const balanceChange = BigInt(jettonBalanceBefore) - BigInt(jettonBalanceAfter);

        } else {
        }

        return { result: 'completed', newSeqno: currentSeqno };
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}

async function main() {
    const fromMnemonic = "example gospel ..."; // 
    const toAddress = "xxx"; 
    const jettonMasterAddress = "EQCxE6mUtQJKFnGfaROTKOt1lZbDiiX1kCixRv7Nw2Id_sDs"; 
    const transferAmount = "0.1"; 

    await transferJettonTokens(fromMnemonic, toAddress, jettonMasterAddress, transferAmount);

 
}
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
main().catch(console.error);

The above is my code. After running the code, I can see a record of a large amount of TON transfer in the wallet, but the processing will fail. How should I write the transaction processing so that it will be sent as a jetton USD transfer? Online help
